# Windows 10 machine locks up randomly, power button no longer works

Tags: windows-10, freeze

A friend of mine's Windows 10 machine randomly locks up completely with a black screen, and the fans spinning. It will stay in this state forever. I couldn't find any way to reactivate it. It's not even possible to turn it off by pressing and holding the power button for 10 seconds. The only thing that seems to work is pulling the power plug.

On booting the machine up again, there's nothing suspicious to be found in the system log.

Interestingly, this only seems to happen when the computer is left idle. All the automatic standby settings have been disabled (go to standby after x minutes, enable disk drive standby after x minutes, etc.). Manual standby works fine, though.

I already did a memtest as well and it passed fine.

Any ideas on how to find the cause of this issue?